# Ajax uploadify on smart phones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, uploadify

I implemeneted a flash version of uploadify in my current project. It is working fine on web. My issue is that client need uploadify - feature in mobile phones also (android, ios etc) where current implementation is not working. How can I overcome this. Should I move to HTML5 version or can I use flash version which gives support on phone ( if there ) also. The problem is that we are integrated uploadify in many pages. So that changing the whole code for mobile support is difficult. Please give me a best solution on this.

Answer (score 1):

**uploadify** will not work on even for the HTML5 release, You need to do some coding or you can use other tools like [Aurigma](http://www.aurigma.com/iphone/) or [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

You can also use an upload plugin for jQuery mobile, I think you will have the best answer in [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/file-upload-in-jquery-mobile) discussion in jQuery forum.

Comment: They said so, you can send them and ask about that.

Comment: Mean while I am trying to get any other opensource plugin. Do you have any experience in it?

Comment: I didn't try it by myself but it looks awesome, it has around 12k stars and the most important it is jQuery.

Comment: Yeah I already started with jQuery-File-Upload. I will update my opinion after the implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/missra-kit/jquery-plugins/tree/master/UploadiFive

Please check this link . It is work for me.